# window.addEventListener('load', function() does not always run on MS Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have an application form on a web page that sometimes does not submit correctly on Edge, it instead reloads the page.

It works perfectly in Chrome every time.

I have since worked out that the issue is that the page does not always fully load and the submit listener relies on this.

I can hit Ctrl F5 3 or 4 times in a row and it does not load, then on the 5th it does.

There are no errors in the console to suggest what might be going on.

Any clues as to what is going on would be very welcomed.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
  // Loop over them and prevent submission
  var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    let err = false;
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: "_the page does not always fully load_" You've to try to find out which resource hangs the loading, the code you've posted works in Edge as well as in any Chromium based browser, or in any nowadays used browser.

Comment: how would i go about finding which resource is hanging, the network tab in the console does not suggest anything, could i assume it would be something 3rd party?

Comment: If there's nothing in the Network tab, you've to make it in the old-fashion way, remove resources until the page stops hanging.

Comment: Before starting to reduce resources, make sure you haven't filtered any information out from the Network tab.